# notified-Notify_AUP Request

Tags: apache, http

I am starting to see a few of these requests in my Apache logs.  They seem to come in pairs; first a request for /notified-Notify_AUP followed by a request for /verify-Notify_AUP.

The requests come with a google search referrer pointing to my site.  The requests seem to come from legit companies -- of course anything can be hacked.

I have never heard of these files, unlike so many of the other fishing expeditions aimed at all of our sites.  Is this something new or are these legit and I am supposed to be providing some sort of reply?

Thanks,

Boggle

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No.  I still see them and have no idea.

Comment: As of now, I have not seen one in my logs for 30 days or so.  It is kind of off my radar now.

Comment: I did one last google on this and it appears it is some sort of probe for or attack on ProxySG.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that this is an attack on ProxySG.  Since I do not have a ProxySG box, I can safely ignore this problem.